# Probability of an Ace given that other is Ace?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

**Question:**

A person draws two card and shows one of them, which is an Ace. What is the probability that other card is also an Ace?

**My Approaches:**

1. Since it is given that one card is Ace, there are 51 cards left. 3 of them are Aces. Probability is simply 3/51.
2. SInce the question is what is the probability of another ace it should be (Probability of one Ace)*(Probability of 2nd Ace) i.e. (4/52)(3/51)

**Counter Arguments:**
My friend thinks it is not right. And propose following:

1. 1st approach is not correct. It simply implies choosing of one Ace from a decck from which an Ace is removed.
2. 2nd approach is not correct as it implies probability of  choosing of two aces one after another. Does not really fits to the case that given a person already drawn an ace and now talking about only the second card.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Approach 1 is correct. The counterargument actually explains why it's correct (lol): after choosing the first ace, the second card is just a random card from a deck with 1 fewer ace.

Comment: This, like your previous question, again depends heavily on your friend's decision process for which card to show you.  If he always shows you an ace if it is available you will get one answer.  If he picks which of the two cards to show you randomly then you will get a different answer.

Comment: There are even more possible protocols.  Maybe he only shows you an Ace when he has drawn two Aces, and the probability is $1$.  Maybe he only shows you an Ace when he has drawn exactly one Ace and the probability is $0$.  We can't say much of anything about probability if we don't know what the probability space is.

Comment: Leaving the details of the calculations to you, the probability if he always chooses to show an ace if it is available will be $\dfrac{4\cdot 3}{4\cdot 3 + 4\cdot 48\cdot 2}=\dfrac{1}{33}$.  If he picks which of the two cards to show you uniformly at random, then it happens to be $\dfrac{3}{53}$.  If he acts in any way different than this, there is not enough information to answer

Comment: The issue here is almost identical to the one in your prior question.  Take some time to review the answers you received to that one.